# Django TruncHour + annotate Count not inlcuding hours with zero rows

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model `EventData`

```
class EventData(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    session = models.ForeignKey(EventSession, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(EventName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and a query

```
event_volume = IngestModels.EventData.objects.filter(product=my_product, created__date=selected_date)
  .annotate(hour=TruncHour('created'))
  .annotate(event_count=Count('*'))
  .values("hour", "event_count")
```

that yields results like

| hour | event_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-12 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-11-12 01:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-11-12 02:00:00 | 7 |
| 2021-11-12 05:00:00 | 5 |
| 2021-11-12 06:00:00 | 9 |
| 2021-11-12 09:00:00 | 10 |
| 2021-11-12 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:00 | 9 |

You'll notice that there are times when no events occurred, so the hour is omitted from the row. I'd really like each hour to be present and `0` in the `event_count` column if no events occurred. So something like:

| hour | event_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-12 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-11-12 01:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-11-12 02:00:00 | 7 |
| 2021-11-12 03:00:00 | 0 |
| 2021-11-12 04:00:00 | 0 |
| 2021-11-12 05:00:00 | 5 |
| 2021-11-12 06:00:00 | 9 |
| 2021-11-12 07:00:00 | 0 |
| 2021-11-12 08:00:00 | 0 |
| 2021-11-12 09:00:00 | 10 |
| 2021-11-12 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-11-12 11:00:00 | 0 |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:00 | 9 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm using PostgreSQL as my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this via ORM, but it was trivial to pad the data out in regular Python code.

```
def time_series_pad_zeros(time_series):
    result = []
    for i in range(0,24):
        found = False
        for data in time_series:
            if data['hour'].hour == i:
                found = True
                result.append({ "hour": i, "event_count": data['event_count'] })

        if not found:
            result.append({ "hour": i, "event_count": 0 })

    return result
```